# How to access object inside a function?

Tags: jquery, function, google-maps

I have this code:

```
var mapInit = function() {
    var trasaVyska = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: "/i/yellow-dot.png",
        visible: false
    });

    var info = $("#info");

    var zobraz_trasu_na_mape = function(id) {
        zobrazInfo(null, id);
    }

    // more lines of code
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    mapInit();

    console.log(mapInit.trasaVyska);
    console.log(mapInit.info);
    console.log(mapInit.zobraz_trasu_na_mape);
});
```

Why is it showing in console "undefined" for all three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There comes the closure,

Try,

```
var mapInit = function() {

    var trasaVyska = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: "/i/yellow-dot.png",
        visible: false
    });
    var info = $("#info");
    var zobraz_trasu_na_mape = function(id) {
        zobrazInfo(null, id);
    }

    return {   trasaVyska : trasaVyska, 
              info:info,
              zobraz_trasu_na_mape:zobraz_trasu_na_mape 
          };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var obj = mapInit();
    console.log(obj.trasaVyska);
    console.log(obj.info);
    console.log(obj.zobraz_trasu_na_mape);
});
```

*Problem with your code:*

By default all the functions would return undefined. And undefined does not have any property under it.

Comment: This doesn't have much of anything to do with closures, you're just returning an object (which is a useful way to do what the OP asked).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually we are accessing the local scope variables after their scope got expired. Its a kind of closure right?? We are doing it by means of returning the required varibles in an object. Am i missing anything here?? THans

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: No, you're not accessing local scope variables after the function returns. You're making **a copy** of their values, exactly like `var a = 42; return a;` does. There *is* a closure here (`zobraz_trasu_na_mape`), but that's not why returning the object works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just found the following snippet in this link(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) `function makeFunc() {
  var name = "Mozilla";
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
}

var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();` They are saying that this is a closure. Our suggestion is also schematically identical with this. Right??

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: As I said above, `zobraz_trasu_na_mape` is a closure, yes, but that's not why what you're returning works. It's tangential to the question, not central to it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok thanks.. I just got confused, let me have a look at it again to get a fine grip over it.. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it showing in console "undefined" for all three?

There must be more to your function (specifically, it must be returning *something*), otherwise it wouldn't be showing `undefined`, it would be throwing an error. (Because if it didn't return anything, the result of calling it would be `undefined`, and doing `.trasaVyska` on `undefined` would throw a `TypeError`.)

Fundamentally, the variables *inside* a function are not available to the code *calling* the function; in fact, once the call completes, in the normal case they don't exist at all. (In your case they will [in theory] if you return the `zobraz_trasu_na_mape` function, since it's a closure over the call to `mapInit`, but that's a detail specific to this code, and as that function doesn't use them, a smart JavaScript engine could optimize them away.)

If you want to use those variables outside your function, have your function *return* them, probably using an object:

```
var mapInit = function() {
    var trasaVyska = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: "/i/yellow-dot.png",
        visible: false
    });

    var info = $("#info");

    var zobraz_trasu_na_mape = function(id) {
        zobrazInfo(null, id);
    }

    // more lines of code

    return {
        /* Put whatever you're currently returning here */,
        trasaVyska: trasaVyska,
        info: info,
        zobraz_trasu_na_mape: zobraz_trasu_na_mape
    };
}
```

Wanting to do things like that, creating properties on an object with names that are the same as the variables we use for the values, is so common that in ES6 the syntax is getting simpler:

```
// ES6 only
return {
    /* Put whatever you're currently returning here */,
    trasaVyska,
    info,
    zobraz_trasu_na_mape
};
```